# Pagination for two separate model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, will-paginate, kaminari

My db schema is like that
Campaign

```
has_many :ads
has_many :surverys
```

Survey and Ad have no relations with each other.

For listing with pagination I do

```
@ads = Ad.all.page(params[:page]).per(8)
@surveys = Survey.all.page(params[:page]).per(8)
```

My requirement is to get a list of both ads and surveys at a time.

I have to get both at a time

```
@ad_and_surveys =
```

How I get and paginate that?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean with `@ad_and_surveys =`. Could you specify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `will_paginate/array`!

Create a file `config/initializers/will_paginate_array_fix.rb` and add this:

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

At your controller:

```
def show
  @ad_surveys = Ad.all + Survey.all # or what ever you have
  @ad_and_survey = @ad_surveys.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
end
```

at view:

```
<%= will_paginate @ad_and_survey %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below :

```
@ads = Ad.all
@surveys = Survey.all
sorted_array_of_ads_and_surveys = (@ads.to_a + @surveys.to_a).sort_by { |k| k["created_at"] }
@desired_output = sorted_array_of_ads_and_surveys.page(params[:page]).per(8)
```

`sorted_array_of_ads_and_surveys` is combination of sorted @ads and @surveys. So you get combination of ads and surveys. Otherwise ads listed first and then survey won't look good.

Comment: NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x0000000694a678>):

Comment: You need to require `require 'will_paginate/array'` in your code. If you are using will paginate. If you are using `kaminari` it will work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use two different parameters to paginate through two different tables at the same time:

For example:

**Controller:**

```
@ads = Ad.all.page(params[:ads_page]).per(8)
@surveys = Survey.all.page(params[:surveys_page]).per(8)
```

**View:**

```
<%= will_paginate @ads, param_name: :ads_page %>
<%= will_paginate @surveys, param_name: :surveys_page %>
```